# Is there a way to define multi-param traits in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Haskell, I can define a type class that references two or more types:

```hs
class Combiner a b c where
  combine :: a -> b -> c
```

This is called a multi-param type class. Is there a way to write an equivalent trait in Rust, either directly or via a macro that achieves a similar effect? Something like:

```
trait Combiner {
    fn combine(&self1, &self2) -> self3;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can parameterize traits:

```
trait Combiner<A, B, C> {
    fn combine(a: &A, b: &B) -> C;
}
```

[on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1b8c596c61af59caa60deb657425513)

Comment: It's probably more idiomatic for the return type, C, to be an associated type. [See here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ba7871b9211321cdff0cb6f8d82d5c5). Typically, returned types are determined by the `impl`, which may accept types parametrically (possibly with trait restrictions). Note this doesn't actually restrict the parameterization, if the `impl` supports it.

Comment: @Zarenor Some would not agree with you. That an opinion to use or not use associated type. Generic work perfectly too.

Comment: @Zarenor How does it not restrict the parameterisation? In one version A,B,C are all independent, and in another `C` is determined by A and B no?

Comment: @Cubic I suppose it depends on how sensible your implementation is. Generally, A and B will necessarily determine the set of options for the type of C. But one can imagine a trivial, if useless, broad implementation, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c804c889511cb07c746f187b97aa318e). It's not fully unconstrained, but I can't imagine anything less constrained being useful - though there are surely more useful constraints

Comment: "Generally, A and B will necessarily determine the set of options for the type of C."

No, that's just incorrect. Just because you can obtain a `C` somehow given an `A` and a `B` that doesn't mean the `C` is determined from that. For example, `A` could be a stream, `B` a generic deserializer and `C` the thing you're deserializing, with the constructor of `C` controlling how exactly that happens. It's a common enough situation that there is a dependency between the generic parameters, but it's not the _only_ situation that occurs in practice.

Comment: This is a reasonable point. But my point is the rust-y way to do what you propose is probably a marker trait on deserialized types `C`, and a deserializer parameterized on that trait. The result type is still inferable, and parameterization becomes exposed on the generic deserializer - which otherwise would require a repeat of the type `C` in the generic `B`.
I never argued that the proposed solution is invalid. Just that for a trait whose main point is some conversion `fn(A,B) -> C` , the *idiomatic* thing to do is probably use an associated type for `C`