# Is there a way to implement Rust traits based on properties?

Tags: rust

Assuming I have two structs:

```rust
pub struct Vector3D {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}

pub struct Point3D {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}
```

I want to the `Add` trait like so:

```rust
impl Add for Vector3D {
    type Output = Vector3D;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Vector3D {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}

impl Add<Point3D> for Vector3D {
    type Output = Point3D;

    fn add(self, other: Point3D) -> Self::Output {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}

impl Add<Vector3D> for Point3D {
    type Output = Point3D;

    fn add(self, other: Vector3D) -> Self::Output {
        Point3D {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}
```

however it seems like there must be a better way to do this, at least for the reciplicating implementations between `Vector3D` and `Point3D`.

I tried to combine `Vector3D` and `Point3D` into a single type but that didn't seem very scalable so I abandoned that path very quickly.

I looked into [parameterizing traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416624/is-there-a-way-to-define-multi-param-traits-in-rust), and simply not implementing them on my struct but I kind of like the idea of having the trait directly on my structs so I can use it in a more functional style.

Would appreciate input :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_Add {
    ( $( impl Add<$other:ty> for $self:ty; )+ ) => {
        $( impl Add<$other> for $self {
            type Output = Self;
            
            fn add(self, other: $other) -> Self::Output {
                Self {
                    x: self.x + other.x,
                    y: self.y + other.y,
                    z: self.z + other.z,
                }
            }
        } )+
    };
}

impl_Add! {
    impl Add<Vector3D> for Vector3D;
    impl Add<Point3D> for Vector3D;
    impl Add<Vector3D> for Point3D;
}
```